# Read a file which has particular structure in C

Tags: c, fgets

I have a file which has the format as following:

```
*Elset, elset = _121:0_125:0
1,
4,
6,
8,
*Elset, elset = _122:0
5,
7,
2,
```

In this file, "121:0", "125:0" and "122:0" are the names of each layer and the subsequent data set belongs to this layer. What I need to do is to store those data sets for each layer. If there are two layers in the same time, it means the subsequent data set belongs to both of them. The problem is that I don't know how many "Elset, elset = ..." are there and how many data for each layer. Can anybody give a hint? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is highly probable [`fscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), and/or [`fread()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) will be involved in one form or another, so I would advise reading the documentation on some/all of them. [`strtok_r()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) may come in handy as well.

Comment: You need to post some code in order to get help. You'll want to use `malloc()` to store the content if you don't know the size of the data up front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*Elset, elset = _121:0_125:0
1,
```

You can do this with something like:

```
char line[whatever_max];
int target[2000]; // track data set number to populate
int target_pos = 0;
while (fgets(line, whatever_max, fd))
{
    int lhs, rhs, total_chars_used, chars_used;
    if (sscanf(line, "*Elset, elset = _%d:%d%n", &lhs, &rhs, &total_chars_used) == 2)
    {
        // somehow, record lhs:rhs as a target data set being loaded...
        target_pos = 0;
        target[target_pos++] = lhs;
        target[target_pos++] = rhs;

        while (sscanf(line + total_chars_used, "_%d:%d%n",
                      &lhs, %rhs, &chars_used) == 2)
        {
            target[target_pos++] = lhs;
            target[target_pos++] = rhs;
            total_chars_used += chars_used;
        }
    }
    else if (sscanf(line, "%d,", &data) == 1)
         // add data to all current targets...
    else
        assert(!"unparsable line");
}
```

Exact details depend on your data set storage structures.

Comment: @JinYan: you're welcome - few corrects re chars_used/total_chars_used above - cheers.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY well spotted - fixed.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef int Type;

#define INT 1
#define STR 2

typedef struct vector {
    Type type;
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
    void *array;
} Vector;

Vector *vec_make(Type type);
void vec_push(Vector* v, ...);
size_t vec_size(Vector *v);
void* vec_getArray(Vector *v);
void vec_drop(Vector *v);

typedef struct elset {
    Vector* layer;
    Vector* data;
} Elset;

#define RECORD_MAX 10

int main(void){
    Elset elset[RECORD_MAX];
    int input_count=-1;
    FILE *fp;
    char buff[1024];

    fp=fopen("data.txt", "r");
    while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp)){
        if(*buff == '*'){
            char *p;

            input_count += 1;//countup
            elset[input_count].layer = vec_make(STR);
            elset[input_count].data =vec_make(INT);
            for(p=strchr(buff, '_');p=strtok(p, "_\n");p=NULL){
                vec_push(elset[input_count].layer, strdup(p));
            }
        } else {
            vec_push(elset[input_count].data, atoi(buff));
        }
    }
    input_count += 1;
    fclose(fp);

    {   //check print
        int i, j, layerSize, dataSize;
        int *datas;
        char **layers;

        for(i=0;i<input_count;++i){
            layerSize=vec_size(elset[i].layer);
            layers=(char**)vec_getArray(elset[i].layer);
            for(j=0;j<layerSize;++j)
                printf("%s ", layers[j]);
            printf("\n");

            dataSize=vec_size(elset[i].data);
            datas=(int*)vec_getArray(elset[i].data);
            for(j=0;j<dataSize;++j)
                printf("%d ", datas[j]);
            printf("\n\n");
        }
        //deallocation
        for(i=0;i<input_count;++i){
            layerSize=vec_size(elset[i].layer);
            layers=(char**)vec_getArray(elset[i].layer);
            for(j=0;j<layerSize;++j)
                free(layers[j]);
            vec_drop(elset[i].layer);
            vec_drop(elset[i].data);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

#define TypeSize(t) ((t == 1)? sizeof(int):sizeof(char*))

Vector *vec_make(Type type){
    Vector *v;
    v = (Vector*)malloc(sizeof(Vector));
    v->type = type;
    v->size = 0;
    v->capacity=4;
    v->array=realloc(NULL, TypeSize(type)*(v->capacity += 4));
    return v;
}

void vec_push(Vector* v, ...){
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap, v);
    switch(v->type){
    case INT:
        ((int*)v->array)[v->size] = va_arg(ap, int);
        break;
    case STR:
        ((char**)v->array)[v->size] = va_arg(ap, char*);
        break;
    }
    va_end(ap);

    if(++v->size == v->capacity)
        v->array=realloc(v->array, TypeSize(v->type)*(v->capacity += 16));
}

size_t vec_size(Vector *v){
    return v->size;
}

void* vec_getArray(Vector *v){
    return v->array;
}

void vec_drop(Vector *v){
    free(v->array);
    free(v);
}
```